# Ошибка при скачиваний pillow

Tags: python, github, pip

смотрите я взял начал скачивать все файлы из requiremets.txt
но после у меня выходит ошибка в во время скачиваний и запуске
Building wheels for collected packages: coverage, olefile, Pillow, simplegeneric, win-unicode-console
Building wheel for coverage (setup.py) ... done
Created wheel for coverage: filename=coverage-4.3.4-py3-none-any.whl size=163033 sha256=f65dd4135744767ae5d0ce64d26b80a505f797918dcec460f143c8395c033fc2
Stored in directory: c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b0\1f\f3\a95a1a53dbe658f0548a5887aebb6da8196c4ea0b5dbbfd292
Building wheel for olefile (setup.py) ... done
Created wheel for olefile: filename=olefile-0.44-py3-none-any.whl size=47815 sha256=89fd884880dd9abbc27048de160427b9e8af69db247ef13d585ecb027eec2064
Stored in directory: c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\dd\82\36\512fd11f43265ec0a65e0eb4f6b42b05584b8cfac3aa11c11c
Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [178 lines of output]
Single threaded build for windows
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\OleFileIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
copying PIL_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\PIL
running egg_info
writing Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs_static'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext

я знаю что PIL вместе с pillow не работает но я не знаю как сделать так что бы
PIL не устанавливался с pillow

Comment: В показанном вами тексте не видно ошибки. Вы точно показали в вопросе весь текст?

Comment: Однако странно, что Pillow у вас начал пытаться компилироваться. Может, забейте болт на requirements.txt и просто вручную установите последнюю версию Pillow?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.